# module radio for micro:bit (python)

Tags: python, bbc-microbit

here is my code for my microbit in python

so i want to know how do i send the target_x and the target_y from the microbit 1 to the second microbit ?

microbit 1 :

```
radio.on()
target_x = random.randint(0,4)
target_y = random.randint(0,4)
if button_a.was.pressed():
    radio.send()
```

microbit 2 :

```
radio.on()
order = radio.receive()
microbit.display.set_pixel(target_x,target_y,7)
```

so i want to know how do i send the target_x and the target_y from the microbit 1 to the second microbit ?

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested the code below using two microbits. I put in an 'except, try' clause on the receiver in case the message is corrupted. There is more error checking that should be implemented to make a reliable wireless interface, but this answers the question.

radio_send_randints.py

```
''' transmit random x and y on button push '''
import random
from microbit import *
import radio

radio.config(group=0)
radio.on()

while True:
    if button_a.was_pressed():
        target_x = random.randint(0,4)
        target_y = random.randint(4)
        message = "{},{}".format(target_x, target_y)
        radio.send(message)
    sleep(100)
```

radio_receive_randints.py

```
from microbit import *
import radio

radio.config(group=0)
radio.on()

while True:
    incoming = radio.receive()
    if incoming:
        try:
            target_x, target_y = incoming.split(',')
        except:
            continue
        display.set_pixel(int(target_x), int(target_y), 7)
```